# Why are user-defined types as fast and compact as built-in language types in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have reviewed a lot of documentation but I can not find a specific answer to this.

**Julia** standard primitive types are all defined in the language itself and that Julia lets you declare your own primitive types, but I do not know if that's the reason why a type defined by a programmer is as fast and compact as the built-in ones. I've even checked the source code on GitHub, more specifically [bool.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/boot.jl)
that is where the numerical types as int are defined, but I do not dare to make speculations.
Can someone give me a specific answer please? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a difficult question to answer precisely and cover all corner cases.

Here is my take of a simple (hopefully not overly simplified) explanation:

1. Julia code is compiled to native assembly instructions that are next executed.
2. If the Julia compiler is able to prove that two implementations are equivalent then you can expect that the same native assembly instructions will be generated for both of them (it is not 100% true, but it is a good approximation from my experience).
3. This means that at the native assembly level it does not matter what type you used (built-in or your own) as long as the operation you want to perform and the type information compiler has is the same.

Here is a short example (I am using a `struct` but this is the same situation with your own primitive types):

```
struct A
    a::Int
end

function f(x::Int, n)
    s = Int[]
    for i in 1:n
        push!(s,x)
    end
    s
end

function f(x::A, n)
    s = Int[]
    for i in 1:n
        push!(s,x.a)
    end
    s
end

function f2(x::A, n)
    s = A[]
    for i in 1:n
        push!(s,x)
    end
    s
end
```

Now if you run `@code_native f(1, 10^6)`, `@code_native f(A(1), 10^6)`, and `@code_native f2(A(1), 10^6)` you will see that the generated code is (almost) identical.

You can see the effect of this in benchmarks:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime f(1, 10^6);
  8.567 ms (20 allocations: 9.00 MiB)

julia> @btime f(A(1), 10^6);
  8.528 ms (20 allocations: 9.00 MiB)

julia> @btime f2(A(1), 10^6);
  8.446 ms (20 allocations: 9.00 MiB)
```

You have the same timings and the same number of allocations.

But now consider the following definition:

```
struct C
    a
end

function f(x::C, n)
    s = Int[]
    for i in 1:n
        push!(s,x.a)
    end
    s
end
```

Now benchmarking this function gives:

```
julia> @btime f(C(1), 10^6);
  19.855 ms (21 allocations: 9.00 MiB)
```

The reason that in type `C` field `a` can hold any value so the compiler cannot prove that `x.a` is an `Int` and has to do some additional work because of this. You can verify that this is the case by inspecting `@code_warntype f(C(1), 10^6)` against `@code_warntype f(A(1), 10^6)`.

Comment: That is a great example of detailed, helpful answer!